# Have header fade out then in after appending class

Tags: jquery, css, header, fade

I have a small script that allows my header to append and remove a subclass upon scrolling the page.

However, the transition is hard, and I'd like to have the header variants fade from one to another.

I can't figure out how to get it to fade. It either flashes in and out, or blinks then fades. I was wondering if someone could help me out.

The jquery code I have is below (in it's broken state)

```
function init() {
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        shrinkOn = 100,
        header = document.querySelector("#header");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
        $("header").addClass("smaller").fadeIn(400);
    } else {
        if ($("header").hasClass("smaller")) {
            $("header").fadeOut(400).removeClass("smaller").fadeIn(400);
     }
    }
});
}
window.onload = init();
```

I want the header to fade out, the append the .smaller class, then fade back in.

And vise-versa.

I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, but this has spawned a new question which will be posted later. Here is my soloution below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
        navOffset - The distance in which to trigger the events
        scrollPos - The position Y that the page has been scrolled
    */

  var navOffset = 5 /*$("header").offset().top;*/

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("header").stop(true);

        if (!$("header").hasClass("smaller") || scrollPos < navOffset) {
            if (scrollPos > navOffset) {
                $("header").fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
                    $("header").addClass("smaller");
                });
                $("header").fadeTo(400, 1); 
            } else {
                $("header").fadeTo(400, 0, function (){
                    $("header").removeClass("smaller");
                });
                $("header").fadeTo(400, 1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add or remove on completion of the fade function so:

```
 $("header").addClass("smaller").fadeIn(400);
```

becomes:

```
 $("header").fadeIn(400, function(){
   $(this).addClass("smaller");
 });
```

alternatively you can use animation transforms in the css for the appended classes